# Making new items in an array fade in

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I'm working on an animation in Blender 2.8 wherein a line is increasing in length over the course of 40 frames. I'm using the array modifier, so a discrete rectangular shape is duplicated along the length of the line.

Using keypoints on the array count (from 1 to 25) works, but the new items simply pop into existence along the line.

Is there a way to make these new items fade in, going from transparent to opaque? Perhaps using nodes? I'm going to be rendering in Cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the BUILD modifier (you can also apply it to lines).

BUILD modified let you animate the generation of a line and on the line/path you can control easily the radius/thickness.

1. Make 2 curves: one path (the line), one circle or square
2. one the line apply a GEOMETRY > BEVEL > OBJECT > choose the circle or the square
3. Edit the size of the path with ALT+S (you can "inflate" a node of the path)
4. apply the BUILD modifier to the line.
5. animate and have fun

[image]